# Redirecting traffic to another local port on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, redirect, tcp, port, traffic

What's the easiest way of redirecting traffic incoming on my Mac on port 80 to the same mac on port 8080?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can forward port 8080 to 80 on any incoming traffic with the following ipfw rule:

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1:8080 tcp from any to me 80 in
```

Note that after restart the rule will be gone unless you make it permanent using launchd.